# How can I set the date/time of a mail in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email

How can I change the Date/Time Thunderbird inserts in the Mails `Date` Header? I want to insert a Date which is in the past, so I do not(!) need a "send later" functionallity. I'm searching for an extension which allows me to set the Date Header.

I know that it is discouraged to change the `Date` header, but this is simply for internal purposes, we sometimes need mails to appear at other dates in the messagelist.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this goal by using the [Header Tools Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-lite/) add-on for Thunderbird.

Select your message, then go to 'Message' -> 'HeaderToolsLite' -> 'Change header details'. There you can alter the 'Date' field.